# How to check if one time.Now is after another time.Time

Tags: go

I want to check if time.Now is after another time.Time in Go.

person.CreatedAt is time.Time

```
if time.Now > person.CreatedAt {
    fmt.Println("time.Now is after person.CreatedAt")
}
```

Comment: Use [time.After](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#After)

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/20924303/13860

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do date/time comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924303/how-to-do-date-time-comparison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here simple example how you can check it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    dateFormat := "2006-01-02"
    personCreatedAt, err := time.Parse(dateFormat, "2020-01-01")
    if err != nil {
        // error handling...
    }
    ok := time.Now().After(personCreatedAt)
    fmt.Println(ok)
}
```

Result will be: `true`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [time.After](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.After), [time.Before](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Before) and [time.Equal](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Equal) to compare times:

```golang
if time.Now().After(person.CreatedAt) {
    fmt.Println("time.Now is after person.CreatedAt")
}
```

To check if a `time.Time` variable is empty use [time.IsZero](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.IsZero)